# How do I assemble Python 3 bytecode?

Tags: python-3.x, bytecode

I can easily get a textual representation of Python 3 bytecode,

```
def foo():
  print("Hello world!")

import dis
dis.dis(foo)
2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
            2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('Hello World!')
            4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            6 POP_TOP
            8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           10 RETURN_VALUE
```

But how can I do the inverse of that. Like how would I run this..

```
2           0 LOAD_GLOBAL              0 (print)
            2 LOAD_CONST               1 ('World says Hello!')
            4 CALL_FUNCTION            1
            6 POP_TOP
            8 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
           10 RETURN_VALUE
```

Notice we're loading a different value in `LOAD_CONST` on line 2.

Answer (score 1):

Seee [xasm](https://pypi.org/project/xasm/). You can ignore the fact that it handles Python versions other than the one you are running.

`xdis --format xasm` from [xdis](https://pypi.org/project/xdis) is useful for getting a file in the right format starting out with an existing bytecode file.